Падает апач с ошибкой mpm_prefork:error AH00161: server reached MaxRequestWorkers setting, consider raising the MaxRequestWorkers settin
Всем привет, падает сервер примерно раз в 1-2 дня. Посмотрел логи, выяснилось что падает в момент когда апач начинает ошибки сыпать.
Сначало вылетает эта:
[Wed May 01 17:11:28.778759 2024] [mpm_prefork:error] [pid 1430980] AH00161: server reached MaxRequestWorkers setting, consider raising the MaxRequestWorkers setting

далее за ней идет куча варнов:
[Wed May 01 17:11:28.778759 2024] [mpm_prefork:error] [pid 1430980] AH00161: server reached MaxRequestWorkers setting, consider raising the MaxRequestWorkers setting
[Wed May 01 17:12:25.663388 2024] [fcgid:warn] [pid 1843930] mod_fcgid: process 2119707 graceful kill fail, sending SIGKILL
[Wed May 01 17:12:25.663432 2024] [fcgid:warn] [pid 1843930] mod_fcgid: process 2119872 graceful kill fail, sending SIGKILL
[Wed May 01 17:12:29.069787 2024] [fcgid:warn] [pid 1843930] mod_fcgid: process 2121664 graceful kill fail, sending SIGKILL
[Wed May 01 17:12:29.069831 2024] [fcgid:warn] [pid 1843930] mod_fcgid: process 2121668 graceful kill fail, sending SIGKILL
[Wed May 01 17:12:29.069841 2024] [fcgid:warn] [pid 1843930] mod_fcgid: process 2121670 graceful kill fail, sending SIGKILL
[Wed May 01 17:12:29.069849 2024] [fcgid:warn] [pid 1843930] mod_fcgid: process 2121666 graceful kill fail, sending SIGKILL
[Wed May 01 17:12:29.069856 2024] [fcgid:warn] [pid 1843930] mod_fcgid: process 2121665 graceful kill fail, sending SIGKILL
[Wed May 01 17:12:29.069863 2024] [fcgid:warn] [pid 1843930] mod_fcgid: process 2121663 graceful kill fail, sending SIGKILL

и собственно рано или поздно сервак ложится, если ребутнуть апач то все начинает работать нормально.
Вот мой конфиг файла mpm_prefork.conf:
StartServers            5
MinSpareServers         5
MaxSpareServers         10
MaxRequestWorkers       150
MaxConnectionsPerChild  0

кажется что надо увеличить значение MaxRequestWorkers, но не пойму на сколько, а главное нужно ли какие то другие параметры менять тоже? Помогите)
